# How do I obtain the height of UINavigationBar.navigationItem programmatically?

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I am creating a custom `UIToolbar` to use as a `UIView` in the `UINavigationBar.navigationitem.titleView` property. I would like to size the toolbar height to that of the .navigationitem by obtaining the current height of the .navigationitem rather than hard code it. Is there a way to obtain the height value?

Comment: The height of a navigation item depends on the type of navigation item you've created, but you could always base your tool bar height on the height of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 48):

Not sure if this is what you need.

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height`

Comment: Very "clean" - typical practice of Law of Demeter! :-) It's not your fault, Apple designed it. I am just pointing out how terribly it looks...

Comment: doesn't work all the time.. sometimes the navigationBar would be of a certain heigh (in my case 44) but then it would have a (private, ie you cannot access it via UIKit's apis) subview that's larger (in my case, _UINavigationBarBackground.UIBackdropView.UIView height is 64)..

Comment: This for some reason returns 46, when the height is clearly more ( I'm guessing 64 ). Maybe it's because I didn't set constraints on this object?